# how to set CSS style of Multiplication of a number in CSS

Tags: html, css

I make a 6 item column using the PHP loop, and I want to set the third child of each row border to none and I don't want to set the 3times in 2 rows because I want to show the theme center when the page is going smaller.

how to set the border to none for third child of each row(third child, 6th child, and ... 3*rownumber child)

```
<div class="full-container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php for($i=0;$i<6;$i++): ?>
                <div class="document-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="document-img">
                            <img src="assets/images/book.jpg" alt="book"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="document-detail text-middlegreen">
                            <h2>
                                <span class="parent-position">عنوان کتاب</span>
                            </h2>
                            <p>نام نویسنده</p>
                            <p>موضوع</p>
                            <p>تاریخ</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

.full-container {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    padding: 20px;
}

.row{text-align: center;}

.document-item{
    width: calc(33% - 32px);
    min-width: 300px;
    border-left: 1px solid #5bbcb8;
    margin-left: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.document-img{
    width: 180px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.document-img img{
    width: 80%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.document-detail{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.document-detail> h2{
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.document-detail> h2>span{
    font-size: 110%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.document-detail> h2>span::before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: -2px;
    background-color: #5bbcb8;
}

.document-detail> p:first-of-type{
    font-size: 90%;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.document-detail> p:nth-last-of-type(2){
    font-size: 90%;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.document-detail> p:last-of-type{
    font-size: 90%;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

[image]

is that any way to set multiplication of 3 of each element border to set none in CSS?

Comment: you can use `nth-child(3n)` to select every 3rd child.

Comment: Yay! I have added this as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select every 3rd child using `nth-child(3n)`.

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.item:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">

  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

or

You can use `nth-child(3n+1)` to select every 3rd child **including** the first one.

Like so:

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.item:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">

  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```